# Java Rest API | Linux | HTTPS 443 Connection refused | Code working Fine from Local but not on server | Ping Returns fine

Tags: java, linux, rest, https, connectionexception

Following URL working fine from postman as well as following code working fine from my Eclipse:

```
        String fullUrl = "https://edge.chabdee.com/api/WebMethod?webMethodName=MDMChangeCustomerAccount";
        URL url = new URL(fullUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        String auth = "User:guf!YN8";
        byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeaderValue);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(input.length()));
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String output;
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(output);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        conn.disconnect();
```

When i deploy the code on Server, it says :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:200)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1157)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at RestClientPost.main(RestClientPost.java:78)
```

When i telnet or curl server it says:

```
 curl: (7) Failed connect to edge.chabdee.com:443; Connection refused
```

Any idea why this is happening?

I have changed code by removing authentication and add following code

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          return new PasswordAuthentication("User", "secretpw".toCharArray());
        }
      });
```

But getting similar error. Any suggestion on same

Comment: If telnet is not working, you should check if your server is behind a proxy

Comment: You should also check, if there is any firewall.

Comment: @frankfurt-laravel: I am able to 443 wikipedia https so is it possible that this particular URL require any firewall unblock as able to access it from local.

Comment: @CyrilG.: Not sure about proxy here. We have firewall that i know. But public url like wikipedia is working with 443 but this url is working from my local but not from server. so just thinking what can i do?

Comment: check with your network team to add this url in the authorized URL of your proxy